# WillPopScope not working if the user logs off and back on again

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation

I have written a complete app now, and added WillPopScope to every page to prevent any user on any screen being able to use the back button.

When the user presses the back button it displays a pop up dialogue asking whether the users wishes to close the app.

I haven't launched the app yet, but using my mobile device to test the app. When I first load the app the WillPopScope works on every page. I can navigate to and from any page, and at any point if I press the back button, the dialogue appears ..... which is what I want.

If though I log out of the app, and then log back in again, WillPopScope fails to work and always returns me to the log in screen if I press the back button, no matter where I am in the app or how many pages I navigate through.

Why does this work ok until I log out and log back in again - and then when I log back in, why does it always take me back to the log in screen when I press the back button, not the page I have just come from?

The code on each page is:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Future<bool> _onWillPop() {
      return showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => new AlertDialog(
              title: new Text('Confirm Exit?',
                  style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20.0)),
              content: new Text(
                  'Are you sure you want to exit and close the app?'),
              actions: <Widget>[
                new FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    // this line exits the app.
                    SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod('SystemNavigator.pop');
                  },
                  child: new Text('Yes', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0)),
                ),
                new FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () =>
                      Navigator.pop(context), // this line dismisses the dialog
                  child: new Text('No', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0)),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ) ??
          false;
    }
```

I then wrap the Scaffold around WillPopScope:

```
return WillPopScope(
      child: Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        ....
```

And then call _onWillPop before closing:

```
onWillPop: _onWillPop,
    );
  }
```

As I said, I know the code works because it does everything I need it to until I log out and log back in again.

Please help! :)

---

UPDATE:

In case anyone else has similar problems - based on Devayan's helpful answer I updated the navigation from the Log In page to Home page by changing it from:

```
Future navigateToSubPageMain(context) async {
    Navigator.push(
        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home()));
  }
```

to.....

```
Future navigateToSubPageMain(context) async {
    Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home()));
  }
```

This now works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Navigator.pop(context)` pops the route out of the most immediate navigator stack.

Since, I do not see your full code, I am guessing when you logout, all the other routes are `replaced` with the login page route.  Now, after login there is only one page to go back to and that is the login page.

If you have done `pushReplacementNamed` on the navigator, I am afraid you will not be able to go back to the older routes.

If you want to avoid going back to the login page after you have logged in, you have to do `pushReplacementNamed` from the login page so that there is no route to "go back to" from the home page.

Here is the official documentation on how the Navigator handles the route stack.
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator-class.html

Comment: Thanks - that did the trick! I have updated my original post with the changes after your suggestion on pushReplacment in case anyone else stumbles upon this